# Scipy fsolve wont accept imginary values

Tags: python, scipy, numeric

I am currently trying to numerically solve a system of non-linear differential equations for Heisenberg Equations of Motion for spin systems. I am currently using scipy's fsolve to do this, however it keeps on complaining that my equations are using complex numbers. Is it possible to use this function with complex numbers? Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

DELTA=1
OMEGA=10
GAMMA=1
J=6

def myFunction(z):
   SZ1 = z[0]
   SZ2 = z[1]
   SZ3 = z[2]
   SP1 = z[3]
   SP2 = z[4]
   SP3 = z[5]
   SM1 = z[6]
   SM2 = z[7]
   SM3 = z[8]

   F = np.empty((9))
   F[0] = -2*1j*OMEGA*(SP1-SM1)-2*1j*J*(SP1*SM2-SM1*SP2)-GAMMA*(SZ1+1)
   F[1] = -2*1j*OMEGA*(SP2-SM2)-2*1j*J*(SM1*SP2-SP1*SM2+SP2*SM3-SM2*SP3)-GAMMA*(SZ2+1)
   F[2] = -2*1j*OMEGA*(SP3-SM3)-2*1j*J*(SM2*SP3-SP2*SM3)-GAMMA*(SZ3+1)
   F[3] = -1j*OMEGA*(SZ1)+1j*DELTA*(SP1)-1j*J*(SZ1*SP2)-0.5*GAMMA*SP1
   F[4] = -1j*OMEGA*(SZ2)+1j*DELTA*(SP2)-2*1j*J*(SP1*SZ2-SZ2*SP3)-0.5*GAMMA*SP2
   F[5] = -1j*OMEGA*(SZ3)+1j*DELTA*(SP3)-1j*J*(SP2*SZ3)-0.5*GAMMA*SP3
   F[6] = 1j*OMEGA*SZ1-1j*DELTA*SM1+1j*J*(SZ1*SM2)-GAMMA*(SM1)
   F[7] = 1j*OMEGA*SZ2-1j*DELTA*SM2+2*1j*(SM1*SZ2-SZ2*SM3)-0.5*GAMMA*SM2
   F[8] = 1j*OMEGA*SZ3-1j*DELTA*SM3+1j*J*(SM2*SZ3)-0.5*GAMMA*(SM3)
   return F

zGuess = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
z = fsolve(myFunction,zGuess)
print(z)
```

I am predicting the steady state properties, so the equations are equal to 0. SZ, SM and SP are the expectation values.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, fsolve only works with real-valued functions. You likely want to separate real and imaginary parts and solve the system of twice the size.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any other packages that will be able to consume complex numbers and solve the system of equations?

Comment: No, I don't. Rewriting it as a system takes less time then searching and testing, so I never bothered.